# How can I decide automation feasibility for web application?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, build-automation

Guys I need to decide feasibility of automation testing in web application. Application is developed in c#.net. Can any one guide me about factor which I need to consider for automation testing. I have some basic knowledge of Selenium WebDriver using Java, can I test web application using it? This application is leasing application it contains many calculations to calculate plan. Application also contains many reports as well as graphs to analyse enquiries as well as results.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest some basic links to start with

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/choosing-automation-tool-for-your-organization/

http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/answer/How-to-choose-the-best-software-test-automation-tool-for-your-team

http://www.xoriant.com/blog/software-testing-and-qa/selecting-right-test-automation-tool.html

Comment: Thank you aditya, I got very useful information from above mentioned links.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is definitely good. You can develop a ASP.NET MVC web application in C#, setup some core business logic by classic unit test and make integration test using selenium driver.

I suggest following that you first create a lightweight skeleton of the project containing:

- git repository
- ASP.NET web application
- continual integration with build machine (use TeamCity or similar software)
- unit test testing your core business logic
- integration test written in selenium driver using C# running for all common browsers with good selenium support.

Check that with every commit following happen:

- build is triggered
- deployment package is created
- unit test are triggers
- integration test using selenium driver are triggers
- all reports are collected
- test results are stable (same results for same build number for repeated testrun)

Comment: Thank you for guideline.